# Hover on FusionTablesLayer in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a FusionTablesLayer on my google map and it works great, but now I have to add a hover to it and I can figure out if it's possible. I've seen examples with a hover on different polygons, but I can't use this.

My layer:

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    heatmap: { enabled: false },
    query: {
        select: "col0",
        from: key,
        where: CreateQuery(shownMunicipalities)
    },
    styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#eeeeee',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeColor: '#000000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeWeight: 2
        }
    }, {
        where: CreateQuery(activeMunicipalities),
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#00FF00',
            fillOpacity: 0.3
        }
    }],
    options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
    }
});
```

I've tried add a listener of the mouseover event, but this doesn't seem to do anythin.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'mouseover', function (event) {
    alert('hover');
});
```

Am I trying to do the impossible?

Comment: Look at the code for [fusiontips](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-gis/source/browse/trunk/fusiontips/), it displays a tooltip on mouseover. Unfortunately the examples don't seem to work anymore. [This example](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/mouseover_map_styles) from the FusionTables documentation may help you though (it still works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionTablesLayers don't support mouseover events, only click events.
(see [this enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=223))

There are implementations that add mouseover support ([fusiontips](http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/)) and [this example](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/mouseover_map_styles) from the FusionTables documentation.

code snippet (example from documentation):

```js
      var colors = ['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF', '#FFFF00'];
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(10, 0),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          myOptions);

        // Initialize JSONP request
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?'];
        url.push('sql=');
        var query = 'SELECT name, kml_4326 FROM ' +
          '1foc3xO9DyfSIF6ofvN0kp2bxSfSeKog5FbdWdQ';
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
        url.push(encodedQuery);
        url.push('&callback=drawMap');
        url.push('&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ');
        script.src = url.join('');
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.appendChild(script);
      }

      function drawMap(data) {
        var rows = data['rows'];
        for (var i in rows) {
          if (rows[i][0] != 'Antarctica') {
            var newCoordinates = [];
            var geometries = rows[i][1]['geometries'];
            if (geometries) {
              for (var j in geometries) {
                newCoordinates.push(constructNewCoordinates(geometries[j]));
              }
            } else {
              newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']);
            }
            var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            var country = new google.maps.Polygon({
              paths: newCoordinates,
              strokeColor: colors[randomnumber],
              strokeOpacity: 0,
              strokeWeight: 1,
              fillColor: colors[randomnumber],
              fillOpacity: 0.3
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseover', function() {
              this.setOptions({
                fillOpacity: 1
              });
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseout', function() {
              this.setOptions({
                fillOpacity: 0.3
              });
            });

            country.setMap(map);
          }
        }
      }

      function constructNewCoordinates(polygon) {
        var newCoordinates = [];
        var coordinates = polygon['coordinates'][0];
        for (var i in coordinates) {
          newCoordinates.push(
            new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0]));
        }
        return newCoordinates;
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```